# Check to see if checkboxes in the same row are selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to have an error message/alert pop up when two checkboxes in the same row are selected. I've been able to count the total number of checkboxes, and I know how to count how many are currently checked. Each of my checkboxes will have a unique ID.

```
<body>
<table id="tester">
<tr>
<td width="100" id="A1" ><label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value=1 id="A1" /> A1</label></td>
<td width="100" id="B1" ><label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value=1 id="B1" /> B1</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100" id="A2" ><label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value=1 id="A2" /> A2</label></td>
<td width="100" id="B2" ><label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value=1 id="B2" /> B2</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="test();" />
</body>
```

My jquery skills are very basic. Here is the code I've been using to count boxes and count checked boxes.

```
    $(document).ready();
var len = $('input:checkbox').length;
console.log("There are "+len+" checkboxes");
var count2;
var test = function(){
    var count2 = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    console.log("There are "+count2+" checked checkboxes");
};
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.each()` method:

```
$('#tester tr').each(function(){
     var l = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
     if (l === 2) alert('2 checkboxes are checked');
});
```

Or `.filter()` method:

```
$('#tester tr').has('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function() {
     return $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 2;
}).addClass('error');
```

Note that if you want to prevent the form submission, you should validate the form elements on submit event and for providing a better user experience using `alert` function should be avoided.

```
var $form = $('#tester'),
    $tr   = $form.has('input[type=checkbox]');

$tr.find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        checked = $tr.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length; 
    $tr.toggleClass('error', checked === 2);
});

$form.on('submit', function() {
    return $tr.filter('.error').length === 0;
});
```

[**Demo on jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7QS8/)

Answer (score 1):

Process each row on it's own.

```
 // for each row
 $("#tester tr").each(function(){
     var count = $(this).find("input:checked").length;
     console.log("There are "+count+" checked checkboxes");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(function () {
    $("#tester > tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 1) {
            //more than one checkbox is checked
        }
    });
});
```